# How much cargo do I deliver over the course of an entire day?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**Textbook problem:**

> If my round trip distance is $x$ km, and I deliver $w$ kg of cargo per round trip, and I travel at $v$ km/h, with a load-up time of $t$ hours every round trip, how much cargo do I deliver per hour over the course of an entire day?

**Question:** How does ''over the course of an entire day" change the answer?

**My answer:** $w\cdot \frac{1}{t + \frac{x}{v}}$ kg of cargo per hour.  The denominator, $t + \frac{x}{v}$, represents the hours per round trip I spend loading up and traveling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: How does ''over the course of an entire day" change the answer?

That just means that the number of round trips is a positive integer, so you don't have to worry about "parts of a round trip", you can assume that all the journeys are complete round trips.

So let $r$ be the number of round trips then $L=rw$ is the load delivered, and the time taken is $T=r\times(t+x/v)$, so the load per hour is $L/T=w/(t+x/v)$, and the $r$s cancel out, and your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good so far, but you haven't finished!

First, you can simplify the algebraic expression to avoid nested fractions.
$$
w \cdot \frac{1}{t + \frac{x}{v}} 
= \frac{w}{t + \frac{x}{v}} 
= \frac{w \color{blue}{{}\cdot v}}{\bigl(t + \frac{x}{v}\bigr) \color{blue}{{}\cdot v}} 
= \frac{wv}{tv + x}
$$

Next, think about units. Do they make sense? You are correct that the expression measures [mass of cargo] per [time] in $[\mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{h}]$, but is this what the question asks?

Not quite. It asks *how much cargo* (over the course of a day). How do you combine $[\mathrm{days}]$ with $[\mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{h}]$ to produce $[\mathrm{kg}]$? With a conversion between days and hours, you can write down
$$
(1\, \mathrm{day}) \cdot \frac{24\, \mathrm{h}}{1\, \mathrm{day}}
\cdot 
\frac{w\, \mathrm{kg}}{\bigl(t + \frac{x}{v}\bigr)\,\mathrm{h}} 
= \frac{24wv}{tv + x}\, \mathrm{kg}.
$$

Comment: Yes, I thought this too originally.  But I questioned it b/c I thought, who works 24 hours a day?

Comment: True, but it establishes a *rate* so, for instance, if you work $8$ hours, which is $\tfrac13$ days, then you move $\tfrac13$ of the cargo calculated here.